# Using pyTelegramBotAPI, how can I edit the message and Inline Markup smoothly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm currently using pyTelegramBotAPI to make a bot on telegram, and have a function to edit a message as well as the InlineKeyboardButtons below it to prevent it from being spammed by users.  However, there is always a noticable delay between editing the message and the button being edited and I can't seem to find anything on this.  I've tried using threading but it still doesn't edit the message and buttons simultaneously.  For clarification, the following is my code:

```
def test_callback(call):
    if call.data == 'c':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup([[types.InlineKeyboardButton('Encode', callback_data='ce'), types.InlineKeyboardButton('Decode', callback_data='cd')]])
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Select Decode or Encode:')
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.from_user.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=markup)
```

The documentation also doesn't cover this at all, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just pass `reply_markup=markup` to the `edit_message_text` call instead of calling `edit_message_reply_markup` separately.